# sql server, big procedure performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure with 1k lines and 16 not nested if clauses. Each if works over a set of 4 variables, like:

```
if @a is null and @b is null and @c is null and @d is null
if @a is null and @b is null and @c is null and @d is not null
```

and so on (therefore 4^2=16). I wrote the procedure this way:

First, because its more readable than nested ifs (theres a lot of work happening over this procedure).
Second, because each if block gets a very simple peace of code (a select over a primary key, or a select union over 3 or 4 primary keys).
Third, the presence of variable @a means a union all, the presense of variable @b means a join and a distance calculation, the presence of @c means a join and the presence of @d means another join. Like:

Now I have been wondering about perfomance, and Im not sure how to write the procedure to get the best perfomance. Any tips?

Comment: Show more of the procedure. Are you talking about dynamic search conditions? If so having a statement for each case will give you the best performance at expense of maintainability.

Comment: Please, see my edit, the first case, 0 0 0 1 means a join over features, the second case, 0 0 1 0 means a join over categories, and so on (there are more complex cases of course 1 1 1 1).

Comment: ps: I have the habit to do full path joins in the first peace of code, later I just delete the overhead steps, so just dont worry about the join over the categories or over the cities (i just need to go over the thing_categories and addresses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)  there are many techniques to support queries that use numerous optional filter parameters.  The trick is picking the proper strategy, and doing a thousand IFs isn't the best.

If you have the proper SQL Server 2008 version (SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746) and later), you can use this little trick to actually use an index: add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` onto your query,  [see Erland's article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#static), and SQL Server will resolve the `OR` from within `(@OptionalParameter IS NULL OR YourColumn= @OptionalParameter )` before the query plan is created based on the runtime values of the local variables, and an index can be used.

This will work for any SQL Server version (return proper results), but only include the OPTION(RECOMPILE) if you are on SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746) and later.  The OPTION(RECOMPILE) will recompile your query, only the verison listed will recompile it based on the current run time values of the local variables, which will give you the best performance.  If not on that version of SQL Server 2008, just leave that line off.  Just remember that `OR` can kill index usage, but on the proper SQL Server 2008 version that `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` will use the index.

```
--sample procedure that uses optional search parameters
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedure
    @FirstName varchar(25) = null,
    @LastName varchar(25) = null,
    @Title varchar(25) = null
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Title
        FROM tblUsers
        WHERE
            (@FirstName IS NULL OR (FirstName = @FirstName))
            AND (@LastNameIS NULL OR (LastName= @LastName))
            AND (@TitleIS NULL OR (Title= @Title))
        OPTION (RECOMPILE) ---<<<<use if on for SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746) and later
    END
```

Comment: Yeh, Ill check it. But I get the point. First, I think change all if for else if ll prevent the check of all ifs, second, I can remanage the order of ifs, based on uses. Third, add this option. Hey, thank you.

Comment: 10.50.1600.1. Standard Edition (64-bit). I think it gonna work.